# Difference when constructing an object c++ (cocos2d-x)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

What's the difference when you construct an object by:

```
auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();
```

rather than:

```
Scene* scene;
scene->createWithPhysics();
```

Comment: The first one (appears) to create an object directly, where the second hands you a pointer to an object, the latter of which is preferable

Comment: Is `createWithPhysics()` a static function? Does it return a pointer or an object?

Comment: `scene->createWithPhysics();` The `scene` pointer is not initialized at that point, so calling a member function through it is UB (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

```
auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();
```

In first example you call static method createWithPhysics that allocates memory for new Scene object, does some basic setup for it and returns it's pointer.

```c
Scene* scene;
scene->createWithPhysics();
```

In second example you creating empty pointer to Scene object and then call some method on it. It should throw exception because poiner is not initialized (points to nowhere).